# repository not found on heroku

Tags: php, git, heroku

Originally tried out Heroku (in order to learn how to use it) and deployed an app, tastyall.  Eventually went into Heroku to delete everything done in order to start over (what is below). My Heroku dashboard showed no apps before starting what is below.

My blackopp folder on my desktop contains my empty composer.json and idex.php test file which says contains code to say “Hello”.

My question: why can I not get rid of the old app info that seems to be causing confusion? Where is this coming from? I see it says: rename tastyallphp.php => blackopp.php (100%) but can't seem to make sense of this since there should be no ref to "tasty..." anything.

```
$ cd /Users/xxxx/Desktop/blackopp
$ pwd
/Users/xxxx/Desktop/blackopp
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/xxxx/Desktop/blackopp/.git/
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
[master bff3b6c] initial commit
Committer: xxxx 
Your name and email address were configured automatically……
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename tastyallphp.php => blackopp.php (100%)
$ heroku create blackopp
Creating blackopp... done, stack is cedar-14
https://blackopp.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/blackopp.git
$ git push heroku master
remote: !   No such app as tastyallapp.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/tastyallapp.git/' not found
```

I wonder if deleting my entire Heroku account and starting over would be easier but thought to ask my qestion first.

Answer (score 0):

The app name `tastyallapp` will be coming from the definition of your `heroku` remote in the repository config. This is what's used to determine the destination when you do `git push heroku master`.

Starting over would be one option, but if you'd like to try to fix it you can do:

```
git remote remove heroku
```

to remove the previous remote from the old app, and then:

```
heroku git:remote -a blackopp
```

to add a new remote that matches the current app name.